# docker not found when i run Jenkins pipeline with Dockerfile for building spring-boot app

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

```
pipeline 
{
    environment 
    {
        registryCredential = "DOCKER"
    }
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'maven-app'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Initialize') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
                    echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
                '''
            }
        }
        stage ('Build') {
           steps {
                sh 'mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean install' 
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml' 
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Load') {
            steps{
                script {
                    app = docker.build("dantesh/simple-spring")
                    }
                }
            post{
                success{
                    echo "Docker Image created Successfully"
                }
                failure{
                    echo "Docker Image not created Successfully"
                }
            }    
        
        }        
    }
}
```

[Below is the error i could see in pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UVXh.png)

I have installed docker-desktop in my machine and i could able run docker commands from terminal but i could not able to run the docker commands from Jenkins pipeline and i have added docker details in **Global Tool Configurations**

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the Jenkins user to docker group and then run your pipeline.

Please find the instructions in this [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)